# Resizing UILabel inside UITableViewCell to fit content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have successfully resized my `UITableViewCell` to fit it's content, but my UILabel is not resizing properly. This is how I'm resizing the cell:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *str = @"My really long text";
    CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(250, 9999);

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:attributesDictionary];

    CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

    if (requiredHeight.size.width > 250) {
        requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0, 250, requiredHeight.size.height);
    }

    if (requiredHeight.size.height + 10 >= 60)
        return requiredHeight.size.height + 10;
    else
        return 60;
}
```

I create my UILabel in my prototype cell in `Storyboard`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Post-Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *text = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    text.text = @"My Label's Text";
    [text sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: why am I receiving a downvote...

Comment: How are you binding your label to your cell? Can you make sure that when you've updated the frame of the cell that the frame of the contentview has been updated? I usually constraint my labels to the contentview so changing it's frame changes the labels

Comment: Theres a lot of code that could be improved in the height method. `return MAX(60,requiredHeight.size.height + 10)`. The `if(requiredHeigh.sie.width` can be deleted since it does nothing. Can you explain what the problem is? Easiest might be to include a screen shot of what it is doing.

Comment: Lastly will the label ever be more than 1 line of text because there is a better way to measure multiline labels

Comment: @AlexReynolds yes the UILabel will be multiple lines. What's this better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this for my dynamic labels. First I know my label is constrained over 60px from the left and 67 from the right. So I know my label will have the screen width minus that padding to fit its content before wrapping. This method will give me the height of the `title` no matter how many lines. I set a lowest height to `44` so that even if the user has uber small text I still have a nice sized cell. The label in my cell is 11 px from the top and 11 from the bottom of the content view so I add 22 to the height for padding.

```
+ (CGFloat)cellHeightForTitle:(NSString*)title
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    NSString *text = title ?: @"test";
    CGFloat hotizontalPadding = 127;
    CGFloat desiredWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - hotizontalPadding;
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    label.attributedText = attributedText;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    CGSize size = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    font = nil;
    attributedText = nil;

    return MAX(44, size.height + 22);//top + bottom padding
}
```

Then in my table I call

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [MyCell cellHeightForTitle:@"Some long title"];
}
```

Comment: this works well, but could you further explain the horizontalPadding float? Why does that affect the height of the cell. And why do we use CGFLOAT_MAX? Thanks!

Comment: In my cell the label is inset 60 pixels from the left and 67n pixels from the right. So the label only have the remainder to fit text. I'm pretty sure your label wont start at x 0 and be the full width of the cell. In order to measure correctly you have to use the available width. |-(60)-LABEL-(67)-| is my layout. Example 320px of text would line wrap in a label with only 230 width so the height would be bigger.

Comment: CGFLOAT_MAX is used on the thing you are measuring. Here I am measuring Height so I use it in the height but if I was calculating width, I'd put it in the width. I makes a rectangle constrained to the thing we know, like width, and unconstrained in what we are measuring, like height. You have use a height larger than what the text content is but since we dont know the content height we use a UBER huge number. If you need an explanation on how sizeThatFits works I can go into depth on that.